# Why is ImageMagick creating 15 versions of this GIF image?

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick

I’m writing a shell script to determine if these large GIFs could be made smaller in file size for web use by converting them to JPGs. This one GIF is causing a problem for `convert`. It produces 15 versions of the GIF. I run the `convert` command again with a -verbose option, but I don’t see why it is treating this GIF differently than the others and why it is producing 15 versions of it.

The GIF is only 11K, so I’m not concerned about making this specific file a JPEG because it is already small enough, but I’m trying to understanding why `convert` is behaving this way. Am I perhaps using it incorrectly?

The `convert` command being run:

```
# convert -verbose Images/made_with_mac.gif /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac.jpg
Images/made_with_mac.gif[0] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 11.4KB 0.000u 0:00.009
Images/made_with_mac.gif[1] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 11.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
Images/made_with_mac.gif[2] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 11.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
Images/made_with_mac.gif[3] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 11.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
Images/made_with_mac.gif[4] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 11.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
Images/made_with_mac.gif[5] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 11.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
Images/made_with_mac.gif[6] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 11.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
Images/made_with_mac.gif[7] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 11.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
Images/made_with_mac.gif[8] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 11.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
Images/made_with_mac.gif[9] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 11.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
Images/made_with_mac.gif[10] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 11.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
Images/made_with_mac.gif[11] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 11.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
Images/made_with_mac.gif[12] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 11.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
Images/made_with_mac.gif[13] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 11.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
Images/made_with_mac.gif[14] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 11.4KB 0.000u 0:00.000
Images/made_with_mac.gif=>/tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-0.jpg[0] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 2.44KB 0.010u 0:00.010
Images/made_with_mac.gif=>/tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-1.jpg[1] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 2.36KB 0.010u 0:00.010
Images/made_with_mac.gif=>/tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-2.jpg[2] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 2.25KB 0.010u 0:00.010
Images/made_with_mac.gif=>/tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-3.jpg[3] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 2.22KB 0.010u 0:00.010
Images/made_with_mac.gif=>/tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-4.jpg[4] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 2.22KB 0.010u 0:00.010
Images/made_with_mac.gif=>/tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-5.jpg[5] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 2.28KB 0.010u 0:00.010
Images/made_with_mac.gif=>/tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-6.jpg[6] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 2.38KB 0.010u 0:00.010
Images/made_with_mac.gif=>/tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-7.jpg[7] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 2.41KB 0.010u 0:00.010
Images/made_with_mac.gif=>/tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-8.jpg[8] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 2.38KB 0.010u 0:00.010
Images/made_with_mac.gif=>/tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-9.jpg[9] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 2.28KB 0.010u 0:00.019
Images/made_with_mac.gif=>/tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-10.jpg[10] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 2.22KB 0.010u 0:00.019
Images/made_with_mac.gif=>/tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-11.jpg[11] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 2.22KB 0.020u 0:00.019
Images/made_with_mac.gif=>/tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-12.jpg[12] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 2.25KB 0.020u 0:00.019
Images/made_with_mac.gif=>/tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-13.jpg[13] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 2.36KB 0.020u 0:00.019
Images/made_with_mac.gif=>/tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-14.jpg[14] GIF 88x31 88x31+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 2.4KB 0.020u 0:00.019
```

File info for `made_with_mac.gif`:

```
me@ubuntu:~/testdir$ file Images/made_with_mac.gif
Images/made_with_mac.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 88 x 31
```

The directory listing for `Images/made_with_mac.gif`:

```
me@ubuntu:~/testdir$ ls -ls Images/made_with_mac.gif
12 -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 11372 Dec 29 18:53 Images/made_with_mac.gif
```

A count using `sum` of `/tmp/analyze_images/Images/`:

```
me@ubuntu:~/testdir$ sum /tmp/analyze_images/Images/* | sort
11875     3 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-13.jpg
11875     3 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-1.jpg
21853     3 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-6.jpg
21853     3 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-8.jpg
28311     3 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-12.jpg
28311     3 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-2.jpg
34223     3 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-0.jpg
41967     3 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-14.jpg
47849     3 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-5.jpg
47849     3 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-9.jpg
48702     3 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-11.jpg
48702     3 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-3.jpg
49836     3 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-10.jpg
49836     3 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-4.jpg
65520     3 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-7.jpg
```

Directory listing for `/tmp/analyze_images/Images/`:

```
me@ubuntu:~/testdir$ ls -ls /tmp/analyze_images/Images/*
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2439 Jan 10 11:36 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-0.jpg
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2219 Jan 10 11:36 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-10.jpg
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2222 Jan 10 11:36 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-11.jpg
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2249 Jan 10 11:36 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-12.jpg
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2360 Jan 10 11:36 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-13.jpg
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2404 Jan 10 11:36 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-14.jpg
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2360 Jan 10 11:36 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-1.jpg
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2249 Jan 10 11:36 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-2.jpg
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2222 Jan 10 11:36 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-3.jpg
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2219 Jan 10 11:36 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-4.jpg
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2281 Jan 10 11:36 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-5.jpg
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2384 Jan 10 11:36 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-6.jpg
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2412 Jan 10 11:36 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-7.jpg
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2384 Jan 10 11:36 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-8.jpg
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 2281 Jan 10 11:36 /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac-9.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `made_with_mac.gif` and animated GIF? If so, when you convert it to a JPEG it is simply taking each frame of the GIF and saving them individually as a JPEG image.

If you wish to avoid this, then there are a few solutions:

1. You can add the [`-flatten`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#flatten) option to the command to flatten the frames into one image:

   ```
   convert -flatten -verbose Images/made_with_mac.gif /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac.jpg
   ```
2. You can add the [`-mosiac`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#mosaic) option to the command to create a mosaic JPEG image based on the frames of the GIF:

   ```
   convert -mosaic -verbose Images/made_with_mac.gif /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac.jpg
   ```
3. Or you can even select the one frame of the animated GIF you would like to save as a JPEG like this; note that this example command will take the 7th frame of the GIF and save it as a JPEG:

   ```
   convert -verbose Images/made_with_mac[7].gif /tmp/analyze_images/Images/made_with_mac7.jpg
   ```

Comment: Is there a way in a shell script to check if a .gif is a GIF animation? Because in this case, I think skipping the file for conversion would be best.

Comment: Thanks! That should work perfectly, since anything higher than "1" would be an animation.